# Google maps directions API to calculate distances causing internal server error

Tags: php, google-maps

I have the following code where I need to call google API multiple times to get distance. The input to API are the origin and destination zipcodes.

When I hit this link,
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(1230)&waypoints=(2345)&sensor=false

it works fine but if I call the API in my php code, this gives internal server error (500) and page is not loaded.

```
// Calling API to get routes
$content=file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=1230&waypoints=2345&sensor=false");

$json = json_decode($content);  // here I get internal server error

print_r($json);
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Is *your* web server generating the internal server error or is Google?

Comment: @AndréDion my server is generating 500. Even  if I keep this code outside loop giving static origin and destination zipcodes, it gives error 500 only.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem outside of the context of the code you've pasted. Check your web server's logs and ensure your variables (`$sqlquery`, `$row`, etc) contain the values your code expects.

Comment: @AndréDion I have removed the extra code, I am having problem with the API call. Please check.

Comment: What does `print_r($content)` give you? Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @AndréDion  it gives Internal Server Error on first line itself ($content=file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=1230&waypoints=2345&sensor=false");) What other way can we make API call?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IilIYp).

Comment: @AndréDion But not working for me. I increased the server maximum execution time also but that did not fix the problem. What can be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to debug. I would try, at first, to output the variable $content on your screen and use some kind of online JSON decoder to see wether that works. If so; you could try to figure out why json_decode isn't working as expected by putting it inside a [try - catch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp). With the content of the exception, we could help you; without it would be hard...

Comment: calling google API script is giving internal server server. Sowill not be able to print $content variable.

Comment: Reading your question I supposed you got the exception on the line where you use json_decode. Can you put the exception; either by using try - catch or from you error_log?

Comment: Control does not reach this json_decode() statement. Issue is with the way I am calling this API.